# Extending Kendo Grid default grouping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, grid

How can I implement some operations after kendo finishes grouping? For example, I am displaying some values based on countries, states, cities, etc. After grouping by those columns I would like to sum the values and display the total after each grouping group.

Also, how can I persist the columns state after grouping? For example, if I hide columns and then I decide to group by another column, the state gets refreshed (All columns will be displayed again). Is there a way to maintain the hidden columns after kendo finishes grouping by another column?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1.After grouping the dataSource `change` event and grid `dataBound` are fired. In it you can use `dataSource.group()` method to get grouping infromation and use it like so:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
     var gr = e.sender.dataSource.group();
     //some operations on the gr variable.
}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to check what exacly change in dataSource it was (grouping, filtering etc).

Better option is to use kendo aggregating mechanism to it. I recommed to try it first. Check [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates) to see how it works.

2.Here is [another demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ANoso) I've prepared for you in which you can hide column using column menu and then group it. Hided columns remain hided after it. Can you reproduce your issue in that example if you still have problem with it?